# Fill an int array with a txt java

Tags: java, matrix, java.util.scanner

Hi i want to fill an array with values from a txt file, but I got the error `java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` when running the program, this is my code.

```
private static void leeArchivo()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Size of the array
    int size = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    datos = new int[size];
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            //fill array with values
            datos[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

The txt would look like this, first line is the size of the array:

```
4

75

62

32

55
```

Comment: But here you aren't reading a file. You are reading user input instead.

Comment: as far as i know, you can use scanner for input a txt file, no only buffered reader

Comment: Yes, but is not what you are doing here. So the code that cause your error is different than the one you have posted.

Comment: Did you mean to fill _every_ element of the array with the value you've just read (each time you read a line)?

Comment: You call `nextLine()` `size` times for one test of `hasNextLine()`. This is probably your main issue as you end up trying to read more lines than are present in your file.

Answer (score 1):

Having both a `while` loop and a `for` loop appears to be the cause of your trouble. If you are sure that your input is correct, ie. the number of lines matches the first number, then you can do something like this:

```
private static void leeArchivo()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Size of the array
    int size = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    datos = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        //fill array with values
        datos[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    }
}
```

In the code above, there is no test for `hasNextLine()` as it's not required because we *know* there is a next line. If you want to play it safe, use something like this:

```
private static void leeArchivo()
{
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Size of the array
    int size = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
    datos = new int[size];

    int i = 0;
    while ((i < size) && s.hasNextLine()) {
        //fill array with values
        datos[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        i++;
    }
}
```